# Possible apache/mysql/php wrapper?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wrapper

I was tasked with writing a smallish program for data input and manipulation. My language of choice happens to be PHP. I have written out the program/site it all works fine is easily portable and everything but have one question. Is there anyway to wrap up apache/mysql/php into a bundle of one exe? I know of [MoWes Portable](http://www.chsoftware.net/en/mowes/mowesportable/mowes.htm) and other options but I am looking to basically wrap everything up into a single exe without much fuss to the end user. My target users are very low on the computer savvy scale. I am trying to avoid a batch file for launching and don't really want them able to shutdown one part on accident and not another (IE shut off mysql but leave apache on).

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator/Titanium (I don't know the correct name -- the people running the company are morons and don't have a clue which name to use it seems) allows you to run PHP/Python/Java/Anything on desktop/mobile/iPad very easily: http://www.appcelerator.com/

(Off topic: It took me 5 minutes and a lot of Googling to remember the product's name. They have the worst brand-recognition and marketing strategy ever.)

Comment: While this looks nice, I would have to recode my entire project with their api. :(